# How to create a formula that calculate the total of spending base on their names?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to create a formula that can get all the user spending on each day based on their names and display it on the **Total user spent** table. The main problem is I don't know how to pull all it because the cell is unpredictable. I'm thinking if it's possible to create an ID based entry then add the total on the Total user spent table, but I can't find a tutorial on how to do it or is it the best approach. I can understand a little bit of programming but I just don't know how to do it on excel. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing it ´, as long as the total days aren't too many, is using `=SUM()` and `=SUMIF()`.

Syntax

```
SUM(number1,[number2],...)
SUMIF (range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

In M22 put
         `=SUM(SUMIF($C$3:$C$10,L22,$F$3:$F$10),SUMIF($H$3:$H$10,L22,$K$3:$K$10))`

Then with the corner of M22, drag it down to M27 to cover all the names.
[image]

The `=SUMIF()` looks at the first range (here `C3:C10`) and looks for the specified value (`L22`, which is the name). Then it sums the values of the second range (`F3:F10`).
By putting the `$`sign in the reference, the value becomes absolute.
Notice how, by dragging the formula down, it automatically changes the `L22` value, to `L23`, `L24` and so on.
Without the `$` on the ranges they would also shift down (eg. `C4:c11`) and the function would not be looking in the right place.

The `=SUM()` function just adds the different SUMIFs together, since the `SUMIF` can only look at one column at a time.

Another way of cleaning it up is using named ranges.
If you for example select F3:F7 and then in the box in the upper right corner, you put something like *d1tot* and press enter, you can change the `$F$3:$F$10` in the function to simply *d1tot*.
[image] -to- [image]

By doing this you could change the function to something like:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(d1usr,L22,d1tot),SUMIF(d2usr,L22,d2tot))
```

Or, if you decide to make the whole thing into a table for sorting, you could reference the table headers like so:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Table1[User],L22,Table1[total]),SUMIF(Table1[User2],L22,Table1[total2])
```

Or similar.